# How to use customize EditText class in Activity?

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

void init() {

    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });


    this.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

            Log.e("afterTextChanged", "" + s);
            if (s.toString().length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(0) != '$') {
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                b = b.reverse();
                b.append('$');
                b = b.reverse();
                MyEditText.this.setText(b);
                MyEditText.this.setSelection(MyEditText.this.getText()
                        .length());
            } else {

                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.toString().length(); i++) {
                    if (s.toString().charAt(i) == '$') {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                if (counter > 1) {
                    String str = s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
                    str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(str);
                    b = b.reverse();
                    b.append('$');
                    b = b.reverse();
                    MyEditText.this.setText(b);
                    MyEditText.this.setSelection(MyEditText.this.getText()
                            .length());
                } else {

                    int spaceCount = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < s.toString().length(); i++) {
                        if (s.toString().charAt(i) == ' ') {
                            spaceCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (spaceCount > 0) {
                        String str = s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
                        str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(str);
                        MyEditText.this.setText(b);
                        MyEditText.this.setSelection(MyEditText.this
                                .getText().length());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Main_Activity layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.mycustomizeedittextsample.MyEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java class is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

MyEditText myEditText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    myEditText = new MyEditText(this);
    }
}
```

Something is missing in `MainActivity`but I don't know what it is. When I run the app the below crash arises:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)   at    com.example.dialogfragmentexample.MyEditText$2.beforeTextChanged(MyEditText.java:55)
```

Comment: unregister `TextChangeListener` before `MyEditText.this.setText(b);` and again register it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `setText` inside of `beforeTextChanged`. This triggers another call to `beforeTextChanged`, which triggers another call to `setText`, ... repeat until you run out of stack frames.

Do not change the contents of the editText until `afterTextChanged` (or later), and be aware of creating infinite loops like this.

Comment: please help me for this ques. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950178/how-can-we-override-gettext-method-in-edittext?noredirect=1#comment36894386_23950178

Answer (score 1):

put your code in `onTextChanged()`  rather then `beforeTextchange()` and also can put `afterText()` change method so it will work i tested it

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `init();`

Most stack overflow errors are related to a method that indirectly calls itself. This is also the case here.

You can set TextWather outside the MyEditText.

**So its might be possible nested calling of function trace your init it create infinite call of function of TextWather callback.**

EDITED:

**MyEditText.java**

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

public MyEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
   // init(); 
} 

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   // init(); 
} 

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
   // init(); 
} 
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyEditText myEditText = new MyEditText(this);
        myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(myEditText)); 
    }


    //TextWathcer 

    private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private MyEditText mEditText;

        public CustomTextWatcher(MyEditText myEditText) { 
            mEditText = myEditText;
        } 


        @Override 
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        } 

        @Override 
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        } 

        @Override 
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

            Log.e("afterTextChanged", "" + s);
            if (s.toString().length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(0) != '$') {
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                b = b.reverse();
                b.append('$');
                b = b.reverse();
                mEditText.setText(b);
                mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText()
                        .length());
            } else { 

                int counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.toString().length(); i++) {
                    if (s.toString().charAt(i) == '$') {
                        counter++;
                    } 
                } 
                if (counter > 1) {
                    String str = s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
                    str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(str);
                    b = b.reverse();
                    b.append('$');
                    b = b.reverse();
                    mEditText.setText(b);
                    mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText()
                            .length());
                } else { 

                    int spaceCount = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < s.toString().length(); i++) {
                        if (s.toString().charAt(i) == ' ') {
                            spaceCount++;
                        } 
                    } 
                    if (spaceCount > 0) {
                        String str = s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
                        str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(str);
                        mEditText.setText(b);
                        mEditText.setSelection(mEditText
                                .getText().length());
                    } 
                } 

            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Layout file are same as previous .

Comment: @lavekhush I have used http://alinberce.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/android-edittext-with-custom-font-and-clear-button/ this link for reference.

Comment: i am unable to access this link,

Comment: if you have please provide me

Comment: I waiting for your rply

Comment: please see the answer again.

Comment: @lavekhush i dnt want to write TextWatcher in every Activity. Can we write addTextChangedListner in MyEditText class it self.

Comment: Please check your mail.