# How can we override getText method in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have override this method in MyEditText class:

```
@Override
public Editable getText() {
    Editable s = (Editable) super.getText();
    s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
    return s;
}
```

MainActivity class is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
MyEditText myEditText;
Button btn;
TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.try_layout);

    myEditText = new MyEditText(this);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    tv.setText(myEditText.getText().toString());

   }
```

}

When i entered some values in edittext then click on btn nothing text is get from edittext why.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code to see what goes wrong?

Comment: assign value back to `s`before returning from `getText` method.

Comment: getText method call again and again and when i inspect the value of myEditText.getText.toString() return blank.

Comment: For a simple solution why do u relay on getText?? Do not override it. Just check and remove `$` from the text if exists while doing  tv.setText(myEditText.getText().toString());

Comment: I want to remove $ when i get text from EditText not at the time of SetText

Answer (score 6):

Why you do not assign back to 's' before return?

```
s = s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
```

Comment: s-> Editable and s.toString().replace("$", "").trim() return string

Comment: My mind that your problem is:
> s.toString().replace("$", "").trim()
Do not assign value to s so it's a death code.

Comment: You can try to return String 'return s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();' after cast String to Editable by this solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702949/android-cannot-convert-from-string-to-editable). But remember that it do not include your EditText style any more.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
   @Override
    public Editable getText() {
        Editable s = (Editable) super.getText();
        s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
        return s;
    }
```

to

```
 @Override
    public Editable getText() {
        Editable s = (Editable) super.getText();
        return new SpannableStringBuilder(s.toString().replace("$", "").trim());
    }
```

Comment: this is showing error how can return string where as return type is editable

Answer (score 2):

```
Editable s = (Editable) super.getText();
s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
return s;
```

I am afraid that you got some issuse here, because the replace return a new string, you can try return (s.toString().replace("$", "").trim(); instead of